# Como posso criar um evento onde eu clico em uma div que contenha detalhes de um produto e após isso esse produto seja aberto na mesma página?

Tags: css, html5, front-end

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]**O que quero fazer:** uma seção no meu site onde tenha uma div com titulo, uma imagem e um texto q representa algo, por exemplo uma bateria (instrumento musical).
E que quando eu clicar nessa div para visualizar todas as informações referentes a este produto/representação, ele não abra outra página, mas sim expanda essa div mostrando tudo o que há dentro. Ou puxando uma página que represente isso. 
Sem fechar o que há atrás, como por exemplo um post do facebook. Sei da propriedade Z-index, mas não tenho ideia como fazer isso em js ou de alguma outra técnica que seja fácil de implementar.
**Consideração:** Não estou fazendo conexão com banco de dados, nem nada back end, só o front, a imagem e os textos estão nas tags mesmos, e por hora quero fazer assim para praticar. Ainda não sei utilizar pré-processadores css, ajax ou json.

Comment: Poste o código e não uma imagem.

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi vc quer que clicando em um botão ou em um link abra um modal, tipo um popup ou lightbox que tenha os detalhes do produto, e depois vc clica pra fechar esse modal que abril por cima do conteúdo da página é isso?

Comment: sim! é exatamente isso, lightbox q chama?

Comment: Vc está usando algum framework tipo Bootstrap ou HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Certo, como você não está usando nenhuma linguagem de back-end fica mais complicado, porém, uma forma de fazer isso é abrindo o pop-up com um iFrame, carregando a pagina do produto... Segue um exemplo:

```js
function pop(e){
  //deixa o fundo visivel e escreve nele o iframe pra aparecer a pagina do produto
  $("#fundo").css("display","block");
  $("#fundo").html("<iframe class='frame' src="+ $(e).attr("data-link") +"></iframe>");
}
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "arial";
}

#fundo{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0;left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  display: none;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.frame{
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  position:  absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 35%);
  left: calc(50% - 35%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- aqui esse botão seria o "anuncio" do seu item, então vc colocar esse stributo "data-link" que é o caminho pra pagina que você criou exclusiva (algo desse tipo) -->


<button onclick="pop(this);" data-link="https://http2.mlstatic.com/D_Q_NP_748857-MLB26626153009_012018-Q.jpg">Violão</button>
<button onclick="pop(this);" data-link="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/guitars-collection_23-2147523311.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg">Guitarra</button>
<button onclick="pop(this);" data-link="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/04/13/00/39/drums-31359_960_720.png">Bateria</button>

<!-- Esse aqui é o fundo preto, para fechar o popup é só clicar nele -->
<div id="fundo" onclick="$('#fundo').css('display','none');"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Segue um exemplo básico feito apenas CSS. Ele usar o evento `:target` do CSS. Repare na URL da página que vc vai entender melhor o funcionamento da técnica.

Quando vc clica no `link` do "modal" ele faz o `target` na div que vc quer mostrar e plota ela na página. Quando vc clica no "close" ele muda o `target` e o modal se fecha. *(observe as mudanças no URL da página)*

Segue o exemplo prático.

```css
    html,
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .modalDialog {
      position: fixed;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
      z-index: 99999;
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
      -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
      transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
      pointer-events: none;
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .modalDialog:target {
      opacity: 1;
      pointer-events: auto;
    }

    .modalDialog>div {
      width: 400px;
      position: relative;
      margin: 10% auto;
      padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      background: #fff;
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    }

    .close {
      background: #606061;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      line-height: 25px;
      position: absolute;
      right: -12px;
      text-align: center;
      top: -10px;
      width: 24px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-weight: bold;
      -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
      -moz-border-radius: 12px;
      border-radius: 12px;
      -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
      box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    }
    .close:hover {
      background: #00d9ff;
    }
```

```html
  <a href="#openModal1">Box 1</a>
  <div id="openModal1" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
      <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
      <h2>Modal Box 1</h2>
      <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3. </p>
      <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register
        form for users.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a href="#openModal2">Box 2</a>
  <div id="openModal2" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
      <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
      <h2>Modal Box 2</h2>
      <img src="http://unsplash.it/100/100" alt="" style="margin: 0 auto; display: block;">
    </div>
  </div>
```

*Fonte:* [Exemplo baseado nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887496/multiple-css-modal-boxes)